# The Musing Of the Eggs

Tags: visual, music, seasonal

The other day, I was working on decorating eggs for the upcoming holiday, and I was humming appropriate music to myself, while I worked.  When I was finished, I was very amused to find that I had accidentally decorated the eggs in a pattern reminiscent of one of the songs that had been in my head.

Here's how the eggs turned out.  I know.  It's a little nerdy -- but I bet you know what song it is!  Do you?  No?

[image: Egg Image]

Comment: This is so good I love it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The patterns on the eggs are

> Wingdings for "Amazing Grace".
>  [image]

Comment: I figured that it would be solved, fast, but I had fun making it, anyways. :P

Comment: @Khale_Kitha: Being easy doesn't make it bad! What software did you use to make it?

Comment: Photoshop CS6.  I wanted to learn how the 3D aspects of it worked.

Comment: The 'n' and the 'r' were giveaways.  I can see someone wanting to put Zodiac symbols, etc. onto eggs, but boring old squares?  I wonder if this would work better with one of the other symbol-type fonts.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman  I could have used the Opus fonts, installed by my Sibelius application, but I'm pretty sure it would have been too difficult. ;)