# The mysterious email reply

Tags: story, cipher

(Previous part [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30532/a-mysterious-letter-and-email))

Having worked out the threat in the previous email I chose to take whoever 'they' are's rage. I deleted the email and decided to write a reply...

Ok, I think its about time you knew who is threatening me. I purposely blocked out the sender's email address in the last part because I didn't want you to know who it was from. But I think I'm going to have to spill the beans:

The email was sent from...

I cant do it, sorry! It brings back too may painful memories. I know, I'll encode the email address and if you manage to work it out I'll tell you about them and my connections in the third part.

> ttuqn-fkvzs@uscsnis.wq.jm

That might be a bit hard...

I'll encode the email I sent back and add that...

> P fqn’z gsbszs av twwqjnz oswtjes vqj ktcs zkustzsnsg as. P mnqf fkq vqj tus Ttuqn tng P mnqf fktz vqj gq. P ktcs aqus pnhquatzpqn toqjz vqj tng vqju wqbbstijse zktn vqj zkpnm. Ph P fte zq atms qns eparbs rkqns wtbb pncqbcpni zks etas zkuss njaosue, zksn vqj fqjbg os oskpng otue. 
>   Ph P gsbszs av twwqjnz zktz fpbb tbbqf vqj tng vqju “hupsnge” zq ktcs huss twwsee zq zks eztwm fsoepzs. P’a nqz iqpni zq bsz zktz ktrrsn…

When you've worked this out I'll tell you about *them* in the next part.

Hint:

> Look down, you know your ABC right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the message:

> I WON’T DELETE MY ACCOUNT BECAUSE YOU HAVE THREATENED ME. I KNOW WHO YOU ARE AARON AND I KNOW WHAT YOU DO. I HAVE MORE INFORMATION ABOUT YOU AND YOUR COLLEAGUES THAN YOU THINK. IF I WAS TO MAKE ONE SIMPLE PHONE CALL INVOLVING THE SAME THREE NUMBERS, THEN YOU WOULD BE BEHIND BARS. IF I DELETE MY ACCOUNT THAT WILL ALLOW YOU AND YOUR “FRIENDS” TO HAVE FREE ACCESS TO THE STACK WEBSITE. I’M NOT GOING TO LET THAT HAPPEN…

And here's the cypher block:

> a:M, b:L,c:V, e:S, f:W, g:D, h:F, i:G, j:U, k:H, m:K, o:B, p:I, q:O, r:P, s:E, t:A, u:R, v:Y, w:C, z:T

Really fun one!

Edit - forgot the email:

> AARON-WHYTE@REVENGE.CO.UK

Comment: Well done, can you expand a bit?

Comment: sorry new here, you mean show my working? The P and b's were the biggest giveaway

Comment: Arrgh I was about to post that. Well done.

Comment: What the... thats my email mate. :P

Comment: @Daedric :P I wonder how many people are actually called Aaron Whyte...? Oh and tetris, you got the cypher block - I made it up using the keyboard, can you figure out how?

Comment: :3 Not sure if the e-mail was purely for story's sake, but I actually went to the site and it's an LGBT club/bar in Brighton (just south of London, right on the Channel).

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - I gave this a bit of thought, but no I don't see any pattern in the keyboard and the cypher.

Comment: @Ok you've got the answer, I wont press you for more, it was 'move one key right, then next letter in alphabet from that key

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Oh!Yes